# Can someone explain to me the meaning of やっぱり in this context?

Tags: meaning

Can someone explain to me the meaning of やっぱり in this context?

> またその先生の方々も**やっぱり**そういう 事情をわかっている先生も多いので 少しわかりにくいところは丁寧に教えてくれたりもするってことかな

Comment: I believe this やっぱり means something like「いいえ、じゃなくて」. It is used when you change mind and take back what you previously said.

Answer (score 1):

It means the same as usual, something like "as expected".